# can't get the value of textbox and dropdownlist when gridview updateing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

**GirdView**

```
<Columns>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="idSupplier" HeaderText="idSupplier" SortExpression="idSupplier" Visible="False"/>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="supplierName" SortExpression="supplierName">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelsupplierName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("supplierName") %>' ></asp:Label>   
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="updatePriceTo" SortExpression="updatePriceTo">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxUpdatePriceTo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("updatePriceTo") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelUpdatePriceTo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("updatePriceTo") %>' ></asp:Label>   
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="operation" SortExpression="operation">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListOperation" runat="server" DataTextField="operation" DataValueField="operation" 
                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("operation") %>'>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="+" Value="+"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="-" Value="-"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelOperation" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("operation") %>' ></asp:Label>   
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="updateType" SortExpression="updateType">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownUpdateType" runat="server" DataTextField="updateType" DataValueField="updateType" 
                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("updateType") %>'>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="$" Value="$"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="%" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelUpdateType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("updateType") %>' ></asp:Label>   
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="updateTime" SortExpression="updateTime">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelUpdateTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("updateTime") %>' ></asp:Label>   
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
protected void GridViewHouzzPriceUpdate_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)

{

    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridViewHouzzPriceUpdate.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    string updatePriceTo = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBoxUpdatePriceTo")).Text;
    string Operation = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownListOperation")).SelectedValue;
    string updateType = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownUpdateType")).SelectedValue;

    //Reset the edit index.
    GridViewHouzzPriceUpdate.EditIndex = -1;

    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    bindGridViewHouzzPriceUpdate();
}
```

when i try to update the row then i can't get the edited values from textbox and dropdownlist. any one have idea?

Comment: you have to update the data source. you are simply binding same data again.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/163877/Row-updating-event-in-gridview-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

Simple update datasource before binding. I have added **UpdateDataSource** custom method. You have to write appropriate code for that method. Update record based on your criteria and you will be fine.

```
protected void GridViewHouzzPriceUpdate_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridViewHouzzPriceUpdate.Rows[e.RowIndex];
   string updatePriceTo = string.Empty;
   string Operation = string.Empty;
   string updateType = string.Empty;

   TextBox txtUpdatePriceTo = row.FindControl("TextBoxUpdatePriceTo") as TextBox;

   if(txtUpdatePriceTo != null)
     updatePriceTo = txtUpdatePriceTo.Text;

   DropDownList ddlOperation = row.FindControl("DropDownListOperation") as DropDownList;

   if(ddlOperation != null)           
    Operation = ddlOperation.SelectedValue;


   DropDownList ddlDropDownUpdateType = row.FindControl("DropDownUpdateType") as DropDownList;

   if(ddlDropDownUpdateType != null)           
    updateType = ddlDropDownUpdateType .SelectedValue;

   //Reset the edit index.
   GridViewHouzzPriceUpdate.EditIndex = -1;

  if(updatePriceTo != string.Empty && Operation != string.Empty && updateType != string.Empty)
   //update data source here 
   UpdateDataSource(updatePriceTo, Operation, updateType); 

  //Bind data to the GridView control.
  bindGridViewHouzzPriceUpdate();
}
```

Comment: but i can't get the updatePriceTo, Operation ,updateType changed value.
For Example,
first updatePriceTo is 0 then i changed to 10 it will return 0 when row updateing.

Comment: thanks but updatePriceTo = txtUpdatePriceTo.Text;  it's return 0 but i changed to 10 same as both dropdown list.

Comment: Can you tell what you have done in these methods **UpdateDataSource(updatePriceTo, Operation, updateType)** and **bindGridViewHouzzPriceUpdate()**

Comment: it's done problem is other i filled gridview when page load that's why when i change the textbox value and update then first it's go in page load and my fill the gridview that's why it's give me old value.
i changed to check is postback then it's working good.
thanks